# Writing to file in recursion java

Tags: java

So i want my program to write all files containing ".txt" to "out.txt". But wr.close() ends my writer and it only writes the files from one folder and not from all. Need help.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Prv {  
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException{

    String a=".";
    String b="D:\\JavaProjects\\Auditoriski\\.\\Out.txt";
    Pomini(a,b);
}

public static void Pomini(String in, String out) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(in);
    BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(out));
    if(file.exists()) {
        File[] subfiles = file.listFiles();
        for(File f : subfiles) {
        if(f.isDirectory()) {
            Pomini(f.getAbsolutePath(), out );
        }
        if(f.getName().contains(".txt")) {
            System.out.print(f.getName());
            System.out.println();
            wr.write(f.getName());
            wr.newLine();
        }
        }

    }           
    wr.close();

}
}
```

Comment: `But wr.close() ends my writer` Then do not call it?

Comment: If i dont do wr.close() it doesnt write anything

Comment: Define your writer outside of the function. otherwise you are creating a new BufferedWriter for every recurive step, and that might cause problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create `BufferedWriter` and close it outside of your `Pomini` method and pass it as a parameter.

```
try (BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(out));) {
  Pomini(a, b, wr);
}

public static void Pomini(String in, String out, BufferedWriter wr) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(in);
    if(file.exists()) {
        File[] subfiles = file.listFiles();
        for(File f : subfiles) {
            if(f.isDirectory()) {
                Pomini(f.getAbsolutePath(), out, wr);
            }
        if(f.getName().contains(".txt")) {
            System.out.print(f.getName());
            System.out.println();
            wr.write(f.getName());
            wr.newLine();
        }
     }

  }           

}
```